# Android - Custom image background with rounded corners

Tags: android

I'm trying to display a background image with custom corners as the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lw9hV.png) shows. The image must be changeable at runtime as it is loaded from a database when the activity is running.

I have tested the ShapeableImageView with the ShapeApperanceModel, but do not get it right:

```
float radius = 500;
shapeableImageView.setShapeAppearanceModel(shapeableImageView.getShapeAppearanceModel()
                .toBuilder()
                .setBottomLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
                .setBottomRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, 200)
                .build());
```

I have also tried to create a resource file with shape and image, without success:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:height="400dp">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/white"/>
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"/>
            <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/placeholder_image"
        android:height="400dp"
        />
</layer-list >
```

Comment: @RasmusStrombald You can try https://github.com/florent37/ShapeOfView

Comment: This works pretty well. Not exactly what I was looking for, but it seems like the best option right now. Thanks :)